# sudo su with password provided in jenkins?

Tags: command-line, unix, shell-script, sudo, jenkins

I am stuck with one requirement in which I am switching to some "xxx" user and it asks for password every time. I am trying to automate this process with password hardcoded in Jenkins job.
ex:
sudo su - "xxx"
password should be given in Jenkins job

Can anyone provide some solution code?

Thanks,
sp_devops

Comment: I don't have root access so sudoers will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Really the best way to do this would be to ask your Jenkins administrator to add sudoers permissions to allow Jenkins to login and run commands as the other user.

Beyond that, your best bet would be to store the username and password in Jenkins' built-in credentials store and use the [`withCredentials`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) step in your Jenkinsfile to authenticate as the other user.

Comment: Thanks @jayhenden.. I would really appreciate if you could provide me the cli for using the withcredentials step..

Comment: You can get instructions on how to use it by following the link I posted.